# Spring @Transactional anotation questions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two methods both anototates as @Transactional, and both performing some database operations, mostly insert.

I invoke methodB from methodA

```
@Transactional
public void methodA(){
methodB();

// Some database Operations

// some error conditions....
throw exception;
}

@Transactional
public void methodB(){
// Some database Operations
}
```

So I want to commit the database transactions for MethodA and MethodB only if all operations are successful. 
So will changes done in methodB still be commited even if an exception is encountered in methodA.

I want changes of MethodB to rollback if error is encountered in methodA.

Do I need to do something else.

Comment: It's not really clear from your post what is the nature of methodA() and methodB(), but I would think someone would have mentioned that the @Transactional annotation fits best on methods of a class in a service layer--you've left me room to doubt that you mean these to be service layer methods with those comments about database operations. But, of course, a service layer would be indirectly operating on the database, so perhaps that is your intent here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the methods called within `methodA()` will be transactional, as the [@Transactional annotation has a propagation of required by default](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation). So @Transactional in the `methodB()` is not exactly required.

Answer (score 1):

When methodB gets called from methodA, it does not create a new transaction as you are not calling the spring proxy that sorts out all the transaction creation and rollback, so the inserts from methodA AND methodB will be executed in the same transaction.

So no, you don't need to do anything else...